# When click on back button on browser it can't display back page in php laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

**Problem:**
I want to clear project history, when back button clicked by user on browser.

**Technology using:**
I am using `php laravel-5.4`.

Comment: Please share your code whatever you have tried

Comment: Remove redundant text and formatting text

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got solution for my problem, I created middleware and used in route file, i got solution.

my middleware code is this,

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PreventBackHistory
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}